# Replacing Values in Rows based on Existence of Specific Value in Row

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

Here is the data set I am working with:

```
ID    x1    x2    x3    x4        x5        
1     0     0     1     .25       .25
2     0     .5    .5    1         Complete
3     0     .25   .25   .5        .75 
4     0     .5    1     Complete  Complete
```

When you see the value of 1 occur in a row, all remaining values in that row should show as "Complete." I'm trying to fix an issue in this data where you can see that at least one row does not follow that rule (Row 1). I want to find a way, either by for loop, mutate in tidy, etc. to cycle through my data set and read each row until it finds the value of 1 in that row if applicable. If it finds that value of 1, have it replace all remaining values with "Complete" in that row as that should be the default anyway.

This should be what the data looks like:

```
ID    x1    x2    x3    x4        x5        
1     0     0     1     Complete  Complete
2     0     .5    .5    1         Complete
3     0     .25   .25   .5        .75 
4     0     .5    1     Complete  Complete
```

What I have now is:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data)){ position <- which(data[i, ]==1)
                        data[,position+1] <- "Complete" }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An "old school" solution:

```r
ncol <- dim(data)[2]
for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
  position <- which(data[i, 2:ncol] == 1) + 1 
  if (length(position) != 0) {
    data[i, (position + 1):ncol] <- "Complete"
  }
}
data

  ID x1   x2   x3       x4       x5
1  1  0 0.00 1.00 Complete Complete
2  2  0 0.50 0.50        1 Complete
3  3  0 0.25 0.25       .5      .75
4  4  0 0.50 1.00 Complete Complete
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  gather(key, val, x1:x5) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(
    check = val == 1,
    check = cumsum(check),
    val = if_else(
      val < 1 & check == 1 | val == 1 & check > 1,
      'Complete',
      as.character(val)
    )
  ) %>%
  select(-check) %>%
  spread(key, val)
```

Answer (score 1):

A different `tidyverse` approach could be:

```
df %>%
 gather(var, val, -ID) %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 mutate(val = ifelse(row_number() > row_number(val == "1"), "Complete", val)) %>%
 spread(var, val)

     ID x1    x2    x3    x4       x5      
  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr>   
1     1 0     0     1     Complete Complete
2     2 0     0.5   0.5   1        Complete
3     3 0     0.25  0.25  .5       .75     
4     4 0     0.5   1     Complete Complete
```

In the first step, it transforms the data from wide to long format. Secondly, it assigns "Complete" if the row number (per group) is bigger than the row number of the row with value 1. Finally, it transforms the data back to the original format.